# Im writing ajax to get the result. "result5" returns some value. I need to add 50 to my result5. But Im not getting

Tags: ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.ajax({
                    url:"http://localhost:8000/solar/foo6",
                    type:"GET",
                    success:function(result5){
                        res = result5[0][0].toFixed(1);
                        console.log(res); /* prints 5.0 in console */
                        res1=res+100;  /* error */
                        console.log(res1);
                    }
                });

</script>
```